# Etiquetas en Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

En mi siguiente query trato de mostrar unas etiquetas diseñadas en `crystal reports`.

¿Cómo haría para que según la CANTIDAD de existencia que tiene un registro, es decir si en Cantidad = 2, se generen dos etiquetas?

Este código lo tengo dentro del archivo cristal. No manejo ningún  otro lenguaje

```
SELECT e.numero, e.fechaemision, ei.cantidad, p.Codigo, p.descripcion
FROM entregas e
LEFT JOIN entregasitems ei ON e.RecID = ei.IDEntrega
left join productos p ON ei.IDProducto = p.RecID
WHERE e.RecID = '{?id}'
```

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos usas, SQL Server? ¿Puedes añadir elementos a la base de datos como procedimientos almacenados?

Answer (score 1):

Maneja el diseño del reporte como un reporte padre. Como el diseño de la etiqueta se colocaria como sub- repote para generar n etiquetas segun el resultado de la consulta